# PHP - include a PHP file within another PHP file

Tags: php

I have the following file structure. I striped out all the unnecessary code to make it easy to follow my query.

1. File 1: /library/class.php File
2. File 2: /admin/controller.php
3. File 3: /admin/user/modify-user.php

In file 1 I have my class.

In file 2 - controller.php I have as follows:

```
<?php
include('../library/class.php');
?>
```

When I run it I do not get any errors.

In file 3 - modify-user.php I have the following code:

```
<?php
include('../controller.php');
?>
```

I want to include the class in `modify-user.php` through `controller.php` rather than through `class.php`

I am getting the following error:`PHP Warning:  include(): Failed opening '../library/class.php' for inclusion`

Comment: ... and `realpath()`

Comment: @Rizier123 In which file should I include the relative path?